# How to write a regex to extract numeric values from a string?

Tags: ruby, regex

I have a string `str = "$ 9.0 / hr"` or `str = "$9.0/hr"`. I only want the integer value from this in this case `9.0`

Language is Ruby 1.9.2

Comment: Will negative values ever show up? Do values less than 1.0 have a leading zero or not? Will the values ever use scientific notation?

Comment: Strictly, `9.0` isn't an integer; it's a float.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'd use:

```
number = str[ /\d*(?:\.\d+)?/ ]
```

Or, if a leading 0 is required for values less than 1.0,

```
number = str[ /\d+(?:\.\d+)?/ ]
```

If you might have other numbers in the string, and only want the (first) one that has a dollar sign before it:

```
number = str[ /\$\s*(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)/, 1 ]
```

If it's guaranteed that there will (must) be a decimal place and digit(s) thereafter:

```
number = str[ /\$\s*(\d+\.\d+)/, 1 ]
```

*Hopefully you can mix and match some of these solutions to get what you need.*

Comment: I used the second one ` str[ /\d+(?:\.\d+)?/ ]`. Thank you!

Answer (score 6):

No regex :

```
str.delete("^0-9.")
```

Answer (score 4):

If your prices always have `dollars.cents` format (which is likely for prices) then use this regex:

```
"$ 9.0 / hr".match(/\d+\.\d+/)[0] # => 9.0
"$9.0/hr".match(/\d+\.\d+/)[0] # => 9.0
```

Else you should take regex from Phrogz answer.

Comment: This requires the values to always have one decimal place; is that going to be true?

Comment: @Pgrogz, yes, this is possible for prices, let's see what answer fits better for Bhushan's case.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know ruby, but the regex should be `\d+(?:\.\d+)?`. This will also work with `"$9/hr"`