# Extract One of Several Numbers from a String

Tags: ruby, regex

Let's say I've got something like:

```
{values="99999" name="22222" store="11111"}
```

with:

```
.match(/values="\d+/)
```

would return:

```
values="99999
```

How can I get just the "99999" out of it?

I've tried

```
.match(/values="(\d+)/)
```

which should return just the numbers I thought, but it doesn't.

Hope someone can help!

Cheers,

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to write a regex to extract numeric values from a string?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8990784/how-to-write-a-regex-to-extract-numeric-values-from-a-string)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Ruby 2+: Use `\K`

Do this:

```
if subject =~ /values="\K\d+/
    match = $&
```

- `values="` matches literal characters
- The `\K` tells the engine to **drop** what was matched so far from the final match it returns
- `\d+` matches your digits

Comment: i think ruby 2.0 or above uses `\K`

Answer (score 3):

Try this regex,

```
.match(/values="(\d+)"/)
```

For just only the number after `values=`, you could use look-behind and look-ahead

```
.match(/(?<=values=")(\d+)(?=")/)
```

**Explanation:**

- `(?<=values=")` Look-behind is used here. It sets the matching marker just after to the string `values="`
- `(\d+)` In regex `()` called capturing groups. It captures one or more digits.
- `(?=")` Lookahead is used to check whether the following character after the digits is  double quotes or not. If it's double quotes then only the preceeding digits would be matched.

Comment: Worked like a charm =] Thanks, Here is my final code: `.match(/(?<=value=")(\d+)/)` for just the numbers. can you explain what the <= part is? Is the () and ? to get the "values=" out of extracted value?

Comment: This is the right answer. Others may cause exceptions when no match is found either right after or later when the data is used.

Comment: @AvinashRaj Oops I think you missed getting the immediate value and not just an instance of MatchData?

Comment: @konsolebox i donno what do you mean?

Comment: It returns `#<MatchData "99999" 1:"99999">`.

Comment: please check this works or not? `.match(/(?<=values=")\d+(?=")/) `

Answer (score 2):

If you use the .captures method and look inside the return value,
you will find what you need.

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

string = '{values="99999" name="22222" store="11111"}'
one = string.match(/values="(\d+)/).captures

p one   => ["99999"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Basing from everyone's answer I can also suggest adding `.to_a.shift` which would return the found value if found or `nil` if not. Example:

```
.match(/(?<=values=")(\d+)(?=")/).to_a.shift
.match(/values="\K(\d+)/).to_a.shift
```

Doing `rescue nil` may also apply but it's a little hacky or less safe.